# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04080: trigger 'TRG_TIMESTAMP_FILE_SUMMARY' does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm having the following exception while executing a component test -

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04080: trigger 'TRG_TIMESTAMP_FILE_SUMMARY' does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:931)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1792)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:334)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.pmiExecute(WSJdbcStatement.java:1620)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.execute(WSJdbcStatement.java:736)
```

I tried to handle this issue by creating a method which is getting the trigger and the flag(DISABLE or ENABLE):

```
protected void executeTriggerQuery(String trigger, String flag) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    DAOBasic dao = new DAOBasic();
    String sql = "ALTER TRIGGER " + trigger + " " + flag;
    try {
      conn = dao.getConnection();
      statement = conn.createStatement();
      statement.execute(sql);

      //get size
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Error on executing this query", e);
    } finally {
      dao.releaseResources(resultSet, statement, conn);
    }
  }
```

Can anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: Do a SOP for this line String sql = "ALTER TRIGGER " + trigger + " " + flag; what do you get printed

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I debugged this method on my local environment and the SQL statement is fine ( I even tried to execute it manually), but when we are running the test on QA environment it's failing.

Comment: As the error says, it doesn't exist. Maybe you are using the wrong schema?